# AngularJS - ASP.NET OKta integration Url Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, single-sign-on, okta

For one the applications, authentication implemented using OKTA.

**Technology Stack** - AngularJS 1.5.x, ASP.NET MVC - .NET Framework 4.8 - OKTA Authentication

As per OKTA integration document, added RedirectUrl - where user will be landed after successful authentication.

**Problem statement** - .NET code should read entire URL if user has clicked on bookmarked URL or enters deep URL e.g. **https://my-app.domain.com/#/customers/12345/details**.

With AngularJS, routes contain '#' right after domain. However browser is truncating anything after '#'. thus .NET code unable to read entire Raw URL using `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Current.Request` This only returns domain name.

**Tried option** - When AngularJS routing code changed to add `Html5Mode = true`, '#' sign got removed from URL (good), however another problem started, as .NET code started looking for Controller instead of AngularJS route.